# Store (cache) files localy in html/js

Tags: javascript, html, file, storage, local

(please apologize my english)

I have to do a public screen ad app for clients (who want screens in their showcases).
The screens will be plugged to an android device and I thougth that if I made the app in html/js instead of full-android, it will be possible to "visualise" the supposed content of a screen in a browser (computer / mobile).

Basically, the app must request instructions at the server, instructions that will tell which files (and where they are) the app must show.
To avoid the systematic fetching of files, I want to store / cache the file on the client so the next time the html/js file is opened, it have all the files witout having to request them...

I have to store images and videos, but I see everywhere that the maximum weigth is (average) 5Mb, doesn't existe a way to store more ?

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FSO.js](http://www.keithwhor.com/fso/). It's a JavaScript library for temporary and permanent client-side file storage.

Answer (score 0):

A friend show me [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) ([Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)), a library / tool that allow to create an android app (among other) in html/css/js.

That make me able to code a single "presentation-code" and to use it inside and outside the android app :-)

Thanks for yours answers anyway, I didn't knew FSO before...